# To verify whether the deployed dll is latest against the dll in TFS

Tags: dll, tfs

How can we verify whether the deployed dll is the latest one, that is present in the TFS. Is there any tool to compare and find out that both dll's are the same by giving the location of the two dll's?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to find out whether the DLL being deployed is exactly the same as the one present in the TFS, you could use a binary comparison tool, like the `FC` Windows external command. You can use it like this (either from the command prompt or in a batch file):

```
FC /B DeployedLib.dll PresentLib.dll >NUL && (ECHO The files are identical) || (ECHO The files differ)
```

If the files are identical, `FC` will exit with the `0` exit code, which will trigger the `ECHO The files are identical` command, otherwise the other command, `ECHO The files differ`, will be invoked. You can replace both commands with something else, of course.

To find out more about `FC`, run `FC /?` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try Reflector's Diff tool: http://www.codingsanity.com/diff.htm

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dll your are building you probably should be versioning it appropriately and therefore you can check the version. If it is a third party dll and you have access to both of them, you can use a file comparison utility to do a binary comparison to see if they match. I use Beyond Compare: http://www.scootersoftware.com/